# How to get user input in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am new to Javascript.

I want to know how to get user input in javascript,i.e. like we have
scanf or cin in C/C++, how to take in user input in JS?

I am using Atom editor in Mac, and i have tried readline() and compiler says undefined.
Please help!!

Comment: You just create an HTML form and reading the value of the input field

Comment: What environment are you running your JavaScript in? This is environment-specific, not a language thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an `input` tag with `id` attribute:

`<input type="text" id="myid" name="myname" />`

Then, in Javascript, you can get the value of an `input`, for example, using its `id`:

```
var myvar = document.getElementById('myid').value;
```